# Showing the Casimir generates the centre of the universal enveloping algebra of sl2

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm hoping to show a series of explicit computations regarding $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and one of them involves explicitly computing $Z(U(\mathfrak{g}))$. It is easy to show the Casimir $h^2+2(ef+fe)+1)\in Z(U(\mathfrak{g}))$, however showing that this generates the whole space has not proved as easy, largely due to the fact that arbitrary PBW basis elements of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ being of arbitrarily high order is bothersome. Does anyone know a way around this that does not resort to a general result or argument?

Additionally, how does one go about computing $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G$ (again for $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $G=SL(2,\mathbb{C})$), without resorting to a general result such as the Harish-Chandra isomorphism? I struggle with this for the same reasons as above as an arbitrary monomial in $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]$ (or equivalently $S(\mathfrak{g})$) is similarly difficult to work with for explicit computations. Is there a general methodology for dealing with general calculations of tensor power computations such as these?

Thank you!

[EDIT: Also if you could not give away the answer entirely in the answer if possible that'd be great!]

Comment: The top answer doesn't use the Harish-Chandra isomorphism: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114020/how-to-understand-the-harish-chandra-isomorphism